# Drawing a rectangle inside a rectangle

Tags: java, graphics, drawing, awt

I feel a little silly asking this but i'm not able to figure it out.. I am trying to draw a rectangle inside another rectangle and the math i'm using must be off. the inside rectangle is always one pixel to short.

```
b.fillRect( rectangleX+rectangleOutlineSize, rectangleY+rectangleOutlineSize, rectangleWidth-rectangleOutlineSize*2, rectangleHeight);
```

Its probably simple but I have been stuck on it for a hour and I have had trouble with it in the past.

Comment: Do it on paper first. Draw your rectangles, use your x's and y's, and the equations will fall out. You know of course that for rectangles it's `(x, y, width, height)`, right?

Comment: I have done it on paper and the equation i'm using works. I think it has something to do with how the draw functions work, i'm not sure. And yeah I know that it (x, y, width, height).

Comment: For better help sooner, post an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In programming the coordinate system is a bit
weird, not exactly as (the usual one) in math.

*---------------------------------------> X + 
|
|
|
|
|
|
|
v

Y +

I guess you're having a problem with that.
The * is the (0,0) which is usually the upper left 
corner of your drawing area (e.g. of your screen).

Try something along these lines.

```
b.fillRect( x, y, width, height );

b.fillRect( x + (width-w)/2.0, y + (height-h)/2.0, w, h );
```

width - the width of the big rectangle
height - the height of the big rectangle
x,y - upper left corner of the big rectangle
w,h - width, height of the small rectangle